# Spring batch -preload chunk related data

Tags: spring-batch

I am reading records from file and I need them to associate with records that are already in database.

The related database record is specified within line in the file (there is id of that record). One item read should have one related record in database. I do not want to read single record from database per item due to performance issues it might have.

Therefore I would like to read all related records from database that are related to currently processed lines within chunk. Is there a way? Or is there a way to access all items that are being processed as a part of single chunk (they should be all in memory anyway)?

I know that I could load all records that are likely to be needed, but assume there is millions of such records in database and i am only processing file that has like thousands lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly a case of custom reader - remember that Spring Batch is simply a framework that tries to give structure to your code & infra but doesn't impose much restrictions as what logic or code you write on your own as long as it conforms to interfaces.

1. Having said that, if you are not transforming any of read items in `ItemProcessor`, a `List` of read items should be available at `ItemWriter` & those are the read items from the file as part of chunk.
2. If your file is really small, you can read all items in one go using your custom file reader / parser instead of reading one by one by API provided reader & then can load only those items from DB in one go
3. Instead of having a **Single Step Job**, you can have a **Two Step Job** where your first step dumps file read records to a DB table & in second step you do SQL join among these two tables to find out common records.

These are simply broad ideas & implementation is up-to you. It would become hard if you start looking for ready made APIs for all the custom cases encountered in practical scenarios.

Comment: "This is clearly a case of custom reader" -so I should create reader that will read a bunch of lines and finds related bunch of records in database and provides objects of type RecordFromFileAndRelatedDatabaseRecord?

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want to read single record from database per item due to performance issues it might have.

What if you read all related items at once for the current item? You can achieve that using the [driving query pattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders). The idea is to use an item processor that does the query to the database to fetch all records related to the current item.